# Laravel Livewire Test : creating a model with a factory and searching it doesnt work without a sleep

Tags: php, laravel, testing, search

I am testing the search feature of a livewire component. Sometimes this test fails, but when I add a sleep(1) it works.

```
    /** @test */
    public function searched_title_should_appear(): void
    {
        $this->actingAs($this->admin);

        Collection::factory()
            ->create(['title' => 'Toto la mouche en vacances']);

        sleep(1); // if removed works sometimes

        Livewire::test(ShowCollections::class)
            ->set('search', 'Toto la mouche')
            ->assertSee('Toto la mouche en vacances')
            ->set('search', 'Philanthropy')
            ->assertSee('Philanthropy and Intellectual Property');
    }
```

By the way Collection is a Model we've created. The database already exists I use DatabaseTransactions. The second assertion always works.

I think the factory creates the model too slowly and the search cannot find it.

Is there a way to avoid the sleep ?

Comment: what error do you recieve when not using sleep?

Comment: It is very very weird, because all the process is SYNC... what type of database are you using for `Collection`?

Comment: I think my error is related to the fact that I am using meilisearch and livewire, maybe the indexation is too slow. In fact when I check the db and the index the data is present.

Comment: I have a similar problem but I'm not using Meilisearch.

I'm doing a stock UpdateProfileInformation of the Jetstream Livewire.
It appears the time to render and check Javascript fails every now and again. It's a fast computer, Mac M2 so it doesn't make sense.